# userform.show problems

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I am making a word document to fill out a form upon clicking a button. I have made a basic form so far named 'NewSite' I have then made a button to click to open the form with the code:

```
Private Sub NewSite_Click()
NewSiteUserForm.Show
End Sub
```

This then pops up the error 'Object Required'

Any help will be appreciated!

edit**

I have figured it out...

I set the name of the form back to its original name of 'UserForm1' for ease of use. The code:

```
Private Sub NewSite_Click()
    Dim Form As Object
    Set Form = UserForm1
    Form.Show
End Sub
```

semed to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you named it `NewSite`, you will have to declare your variable as an object of that type and the initialize it. Do it like this:

```
Private Sub NewSite_Click()
    Dim NewSiteUserForm As NewSite
    Set NewSiteUserForm = New NewSite
    NewSiteUserForm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, I have done this and now get the error 'User-Defined type not defined'. Sorry I am new to VBA.

Comment: The most likely reason for that is that you have given your form a different name. Open it in VBE and press F4. In the properties window - check the name again. Also - check that it is in the same workbook as the rest of your code.

Comment: Hi Sam, Thank you for your help. I have figured it out now! :)